# PHP ImageMagick shrink images to fit into the size given

Tags: php, imagemagick

I want to use the '>' option for resizing images, but it doesn't work with PHP.

It should do this: [ImageMagick shrink](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#shrink)

But it does nothing.

Here's my code:

```
exec($P_IMAGEMAGICK."convert input.jpg -resize x500\> output.jpg");
```

I want my pics always to have an height of 500px but not if they are smaller/equal than 500px. Ya, and the pics should resize proportionally.

Comment: are you not getting `output.jpg`? If that's the case maybe you don't have enough privileges to run `exec` on your host or `imagemagick` is not installed.

Comment: no. there is no output.jpg! i have it installed. everything else works fine. i think that it could be a problem with the syntax. but no idea how to solve it.

Comment: maybe it's because of the '>' or the '\' ?? When I use it without those characters it works. but not the way i want it to work.

Comment: and you want the image to be 500 height and 500 width?

Comment: no. i want every image to be 500 height. the width should come proportionally. so if one pic has 2000x1000 it should be 1000x500. if it's 500x1000 it should be 250x500. But if it's 300x200 it should be the same: 300x200. BUT WHAT I REALLY WANT is that this '\>' option works in php.

Comment: ok, answered where your problem lies.

Comment: you mean, that i don't have enough privileges? .. but how can i control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I found the solution on my own. it's not logical but it works now:

```
exec($P_IMAGEMAGICK."convert input.jpg -resize x500> output.jpg");
```

WITHOUT THE: `\`

THX to all.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are escaping `>` and `\` automatically gets deleted, escape `\`.

Try like this:

```
exec($P_IMAGEMAGICK."convert input.jpg -resize x500\\> output.jpg");
```

make sure you have enough privileges to write your `output.jpg`, as a start make a sepatare folder images/, chmod it 755 and change to:

```
exec($P_IMAGEMAGICK."convert input.jpg -resize x500\\> images/output.jpg");
```

Comment: chmod your destination folder

Answer (score 0):

Put the command into a string and use it in the exec but also output it for debugging to make sure it is exactly the same as the string you use on the command line to do the same thing.

For example:

```
$cmd="convert input.jpg -resize x500\> output.jpg";
print("DEBUG $cmd\n";
exec($P_IMAGEMAGICK.$cmd);
```

Also, try capturing the output of exec to see if there are any errors:

Example:

```
$cmd="convert input.jpg -resize x500\> output.jpg 2>&1";
exec($cmd, $output);
print($output);
```

Comment: DEBUG convert input.jpg -resize x500\> output.jpg 
Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Unable to access output.jpg in script.php on line 127

Comment: the above thing is the php-message i get. and there is no output.jpg ...now it's getting difficult

Comment: Have your tried using the system command and not using the $P_IMAGEMAGICK var? e.g. system($cmd);

Comment: tried it out. doesn't work. no difference. same errors. same problem. maybe it's the version of imagemagick?

Comment: You really ought to use more debugging and see why the command fails. Updated my answer with extra code to do this.